# BlackBerry - Scrolling fixed size text edit with static label on the left side and border

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, scroll, border, edit

Hello everyone I am new to blackberry and I want a textfield that scroll it's text i.e greater than the preferred width horizontally , also able to show label out side the text draw area ( e.g. on the left side). Please help me.

Comment: so you want scrolling text edit with label on left side?

Comment: yes I want that type of text edit. And if it is focusable then that is also good. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be achieved by combining non-scrolling and scrolling HorizontalFieldManagers.

Try this code:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        HorizontalFieldManager fieldHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        fieldHolder.add(new LabelField("some label: "));
        HorizontalFieldManager editHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        editHolder.add(new TextField(TextField.NO_NEWLINE));
        fieldHolder.add(editHolder);
        add(fieldHolder);
    }
}
```

Setting default text code:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        HorizontalFieldManager fieldHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        fieldHolder.add(new LabelField("some label: "));
        HorizontalFieldManager editHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        TextField textField = new TextField(TextField.NO_NEWLINE);      
        editHolder.add(textField);
        fieldHolder.add(editHolder);
        add(fieldHolder);

        // set some text then
        String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer"+
        " adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt"+
        " ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.";
        textField.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And something which basically works on 4.6/4.7:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer"+
        " adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt"+
        " ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.";
        HorizontalFieldManager fieldHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        fieldHolder.add(new LabelField("some label: "));
        HorizontalFieldManager editHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        TextField textField = new TextField("",text,1024,TextField.NO_NEWLINE);
        editHolder.add(textField);
        fieldHolder.add(editHolder);
        add(fieldHolder);
    }
}
```

### Border for Manager

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(4,4,4,4));
fieldHolder.setBorder(border);
```

### Fixed size Manager

```
class SizedHFM extends HorizontalFieldManager {
    int mWidth = 0;

    public SizedHFM(int width) {
        super(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        mWidth = width;
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(mWidth, maxHeight);
        setExtent(mWidth, getPreferredHeight());
    }
}
```

Sample of use:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer"
                + " adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt"
                + " ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.";
        SizedHFM fieldHolder = new SizedHFM(200);
        Border border = BorderFactory
                .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(4, 4, 4, 4));
        fieldHolder.setBorder(border);
        fieldHolder.add(new LabelField("some label: "));
        HorizontalFieldManager editHolder = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        TextField textField = new TextField("", text, 1024,
                TextField.NO_NEWLINE);
        editHolder.add(textField);
        fieldHolder.add(editHolder);
        add(fieldHolder);
    }
}
```